# Transfer data between html

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a client that uses joomla for his website. Via joomla the client is inputting some data to his articles (prices of products). I need some simple way to get this data to my HTML page. I can add anything to to his HTML page (java script, PHP) and I need to transfer the data to my HTML page. My HTML page is the one who triggers the data transfer. Any one can please put me in the right direction how to do this?

Comment: Please specify what exactly you want to transfer? How many parameters you want to transfer between pages? What have you tried?

Comment: I would like to transfer only 2 parameter. I have not tried anything yet, because I need an idea how to do this without writing forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly use the following steps. If you have two parameters and their values are known(Let's assume) 5 & 10 then you can create a button when clicking on it, the next page opens up. So you need 3 things.

1. A Button which is set up to open second page.
2. A javascript function is triggered when the button is clicked.
3. A PHP page where you retrive the variables and process them.

---

```
<form action = "nextpage.php" method = "post">
<input type = "hidden" name = "val2" value = "5"/>
<input type = "hidden" name = "val2" value = "10"/>
</form>
<a href = "javascript:nextpage()">Submit</a>
//Write a function to submit the form using javascript
```

When there is some requirement of sending some data which are to be sent without the knowledge of the user you can use `input type as hidden`. This should be the PHP part.

```
<?php
$var1 = $_POST['var1'];
$var2 = $_POST['var2'];
echo $var1.' '.$var2;
?>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer, but i can not add buttons to the first page, i need the same thing but the button is located on the second page and when clicked the data transfer from the firs page to second. Is it possible to create on the second page this button?

Comment: How will go to second page when you don't have any button. Let me be clear you giving one example. You must be having something as `HOME`, `About` and something like that. You can just embed the javascript function to the hyperlink of `about` page considering about is your second page.

Comment: How do plan to move from page one to page two? If you have a link or a button, you could use javascript to modify the destination URL and pass the values as GET parameters.